# how to mysql database connection in php for sqlyog

Tags: php, mysql, sqlyog

I have a php file to import .csv file into database. For that i am using connection strings like below :

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'demo-eams';
$db_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
$db_select = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Could not connect to database");
```

i am using sqlyog for access mysql database.

My problem is whenever i run my coding it showing the connection error  :

Could not connect to Mysql.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

1. Check if your mysql is up and running
2. Validate mysql port (if its not default then add port in host name)

Comment: What is your php version? if its more than 5 then you should use mysqli_connect like:
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: yes i am using php 5.5.9. but i am using your above code it show the error message failed to connect to mysql (10061)

Comment: Try using '127.0.0.1' instead of localhost.
mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $user_name, $password, $database_name, null, 'mysql');